# Accessing child variables from super workaround

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have the following classes.

```
public abstract class Thing {
    private String appearance;

    public void setAppearance(String appearance) {
        this.appearance = appearance;
    }
}

public abstract class MovableThing extends Thing {
    // ASCII representation of MovableThing moving right.
    private static String FACE_RIGHT;

    // ASCII representation of MovableThing moving left.
    private static String FACE_LEFT;

    private boolean goingRight;

    public MovableThing() {
        setAppearance(FACE_RIGHT);
        goingRight = true;
        // Some other things

    public void turnAround() {
        goingRight = !goingRight;
        if (goingRight) {
            setAppearance(FACE_RIGHT);
        } else {
            setAppearance(FACE_LEFT);
        }
    }

public class Bird extends MovableThing() {
    private static String FACE_RIGHT = "/'/>";
    private static String FACE_LEFT = "<\\'\\";

    public Bird() {
        super();
        // Some other things
    }
}
```

I know that this is currently incorrect because in `MovableThing`, `FACE_RIGHT` doesn't get assigned anything so when I call `super()` in `Bird`, the `appearance` just gets set to `null`. How can I work around this? I have multiple animals with different left/right ASCII representations but I'm not sure how to do all of this in an OOP kind of way.

Edit: Meant to say `Bird()` instead of `Chicken()`.

Comment: The constructor of a `Bird` class cannot be called `Chicken()`.  Please make sure your code compiles before posting.

Comment: If it makes sense for a `MoveableThing` to `FACE_RIGHT` then the constants are defined in the wrong place.

Comment: @JimGarrison I am rolling on floor for this creativity ... :D :D

Comment: `MovableThing.FACE_RIGHT` is `static`, and you never initialize it. `Bird.FACE_RIGHT` is `static`, and is initialized. These are two separate member variables, one won't hide the other...

Comment: You probably wanted a `private static final String FACE_RIGHT` in `Bird`, but a `private final String FACE_RIGHT` in `MovableThing` (no static). Then accept as args and assign in the `MovableThing` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do with your code to model your scenario:

```
public abstract class Thing {
    private String appearance;

    // Require subclasses of Thing to have a defined "going left" and "going right"
    // method.
    public abstract void setGoingLeft();

    public abstract void setGoingRight();

    protected final void setAppearance(String appearance) {
        this.appearance = appearance;
    }
}

public abstract class MovableThing extends Thing {

    private boolean goingRight;

    public MovableThing() {
        setGoingRight();
        // Some other things
    }

    // Require subclasses to define a method that gives me a String showing which
    // way they're facing, when I tell them what way they're facing. This allows
    // subclasses (like Bird) to each return their own appearances depending on the
    // way they are facing.
    protected abstract String getAppearance(boolean right);

    // Override the "going left" and "going right" methods (and make them final so
    // subclasses can't change them). These also modify the "goingRight" field of a
    // MovableThing correctly.
    @Override
    public final void setGoingLeft() {
        goingRight = false;
        getAppearance(false);
    }

    @Override
    public final void setGoingRight() {
        goingRight = true;
        getAppearance(true);
    }

    public void turnAround() {
        // If they're going right, turning them around will make them go left and vice
        // versa.
        if (goingRight)
            setGoingLeft();
        else
            setGoingRight();
    }
}

public class Bird extends MovableThing {

    private static final String FACE_RIGHT = "/'/>";
    private static final String FACE_LEFT = "<\\'\\";

    // This method is called by the super class.
    @Override
    protected String getAppearance(boolean right) {
        // If the super class asks for a Bird's appearance when facing right, return
        // "FACE_RIGHT". Otherwise, return "FACE_LEFT". (Other animals can return
        // different things depending on the way they're facing.)
        return right ? FACE_RIGHT : FACE_LEFT;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to have subclasses of `Thing` that can't move so I'll just move `setGoingLeft()` and `setGoingRight()` into `MovableThing`?

Comment: @unicorn407 Yes, the `setGoing...` methods should be in `MovableThing` (since it's the class that moves), while the `getAppearance` method ought to be in `Thing` (since presumably all things will have some sort of appearance). Remember that in OOP your goal is generally to first classify things, followed by describing the behavior of all things that fit into each classification.